# How can I dereference a hash in a subroutine an work on it like in the calling routine?

Tags: perl, hash, reference, subroutine

I have a perl routine, that makes a hash out of a .csv-file. The values should be checked in a subroutine.

So I have a hash `%my_values` and call the subroutine `check (\%my_values)`:

```
sub read_csv {
    ...

    # key:   headline entry
    # value: the value in the current row
    %my_hash;

    ...
    my ($has_error, $err_msg) = check (\%my_hash);
}

sub check {
    my($hash_ref) = @_;
    %my_hash = %$hash_ref;

    # Get the artikel number of the article
    $my_hash {'article_number'} = get_artnr($my_hash {'article'});
    if (not $my_hash{'article_number'}) {
        return 1, "Article $my_hash{'article'} not found!";
    }

    # check price (I'm in germany, there must be a conversation from ',' to '.')
    $my_hash {'price'} =~ s/,/./;
    if (not $my_hash{'price'} =~ m/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/) {
        return 1, "Invalid format of price";
    }

    return 0, "";
}
```

At first, this seems to work fine. But then i recognized, that neither the priceformat changed nor the key `article_number` is avalable.

Working directly on the reference made it:

```
# In this case, it works!
sub check {
    my($hash_ref) = @_;

    # Get the artikel number of the article
    $hash_ref->{'article_number'} = get_artnr($hash_ref->{'article'});
    if (not $hash_ref->{'article_number'}) {
        return 1, "Article $hash_ref->{'article'} not found!";
    }

    # check price (I'm in germany, there must be a conversation from ',' to '.')
    $hash_ref->{'price'} =~ s/,/./;
    if (not $hash_ref->{'price'} =~ m/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/) {
        return 1, "Invalid format of price";
    }

    return 0, "";
}
```

So i think `%my_hash = %$hash_ref;` makes a copy of the reference instead of dereferencing.

How can I dereference a hash in a subroutine an work on it like in the calling routine?

Comment: Either use [refaliasing](https://perldoc.perl.org/feature#The-'refaliasing'-feature) or arrow operator `$hash_ref->{key}`, see [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref) for more information

Comment: @HåkonHægland Oh, refaliasing is marked as experimental. The arrow operator is good. But can't I dereference a hash (like in `c` for example)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example using the new feature called [refaliasing](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref) introduced in Perl 5.22 (optionally combined with the [declared_refs](https://perldoc.perl.org/feature#The-%27declared_refs%27-feature) feature introduced in 5.26)

```
use v5.26;
use warnings;  # IMPORTANT: this line must come before "use experimental"
use strict;
use feature qw(say); 
use experimental qw(declared_refs refaliasing);

{  # <-- introduce scope to avoid leaking lexical variables into subs below
    my %hash = (a=>1, b=>2);
    check(\%hash);
    say "Value of 'a' key is now: ", $hash{a};
}

sub check {
    my (\%hash) = @_;

    $hash{a} = 3;
}
```

**Output**:

```
Value of 'a' key is now: 3
```

Alternatively you can use the [arrow operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref):

```
sub check {
    my ($hash) = @_;

    $hash->{a} = 3;
}
```

Comment: `use feature qw(declared_refs refaliasing); no warnings 'experimental::refaliasing';
no warnings 'experimental::declared_refs';` => `use experimental qw( refaliasing declared_refs );`

Comment: Note that while the features are experimental, I suspect they will be accepted as-is.

Comment: @ikegami *"use experimental ..."* Yes I tried it but I still get the warnings `Declaring references is experimental` and `Aliasing via reference is experimental`. Wonder what can be the issue..

Comment: @ikegami The warnings seems to go away if I move `use experimental qw( refaliasing declared_refs )` inside the `check()` sub..

Comment: @ikegami I think I understand the reason now, I need to `use warnings` before `use experimental` or else the warnings will be re-enabled again

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thank you very much, but I will not use somthing experimental in an productive ERP-software. It may become a mess someday! - But for others it may be very good!

Comment: Re "*I think I understand the reason now*", yeah, it really is equivalent to `use feature qw(declared_refs refaliasing); no warnings 'experimental::refaliasing'; no warnings 'experimental::declared_refs';`. If you re-enable the warnings afterwards, well, ...